# How to save rounded corner Image using todataUrl?

Tags: html, image-processing, canvas, base64, image-clipping

I need to save images drawn (from base64 encoding) into a rounded corner canvas. The canvas is defined using:

```
<canvas id="thumbnailImage" width="86" height="86" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;border-radius:10px;">
```

The image appears as expected (using ctx.drawImage etc...), with rounded corners. Then I obtain the base64 encoding data of the rounded image using

```
        var imageData = $(jImageId)[0].toDataURL("image/jpeg",qly);
```

Unfortunately, when the image is displayed without a rounded-corner canvas, the corners are still there...

Question: is there a simple way to get the base64 image data, as it appears on the canvas, or do I have to go through the painful pixel clipping ordeal ?

thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems border radius is just the styling of HTML, not image data inside canvas, so you'll have to erase the corner away to get the rounded image.

After searching I found [these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13694183/570812) [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3088229/570812) which taught me how to erase shape instead of just retangle, so here we go:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5xvYt/) (Although it won't work on the final export part due to COR restriction)

```
ctx.drawImage(src,0,0);
ctx.save();
ctx.globalCompositeOperation="destination-out";
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(0,0);
ctx.lineTo(10,0);
ctx.arcTo(0,0,0,10,10);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.fill();
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(100,0);
ctx.lineTo(90,0);
ctx.arcTo(100,0,100,10,10);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.fill();
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(0,100);
ctx.lineTo(0,90);
ctx.arcTo(0,100,10,100,10);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.fill();
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(100,100);
ctx.lineTo(90,100);
ctx.arcTo(100,100,100,90,10);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.fill();
ctx.restore();
des.src=can.toDataURL("image/png");
```

Base on the fact that you already know the radius of the rounded corner.

Here's a screenshot of the result on my localhost:

[image: localhost result]